# How to set a fixed number of rows in android gridView?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am trying to create one gridView in android which have 10 rows and 10 columns.How can I set a fixed number of rows in Gridview ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`GridView` is not really designed for this purpose, it is designed to display an indefinite amount of data in an efficient scrolling manner.  If you want to create a static layout where you can discretely place items at specific locations, you should be looking at `GridLayout` or `TableLayout` instead.

Comment: This answer is right but if you still want to use a gridview then you can set android:numColumns="10" and then in your adapter you can feed it 100 items and this should result in a 10x10 grid view, enjoy.

Answer (score 7):

i dont recommend that but if you use API 14 greater than 14 you can use this code 
set number of column and rows

from xml

```
 <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" >
```

From Java

```
setRowCount(int rownumber );
```

enjoy

Answer (score 2):

I used something like this, it isn't GridView but I had the similar issue and GridLayout helped me a lot:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_recycle_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="10"
    android:rowCount="10"
>
```

You will have 10 rows and 10 columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 100 items then only 10 rows will be shown. There is no need to have a fixed number of rows.

Comment: If we need a fixed number of rows and columns for the application like diamond dash game.How can we set fixed number of rows?

Comment: I guess Devunwired has the answer.

Comment: I've created a GridView and inserted 9 items in it by using adaptor. But it is displaying only one row (3 items). am i missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows is automatically calculated (and imposed by you) from the number of 
    columns and the number of items

Comment: we need a fixed number of rows and columns for the application like diamond dash game.there will no any 2nd row.