# Is there anyway to set the no of row in GridView Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

May be i am asking wrong question. But please guys help me out. i want to display images in Grid View format. 
I have 5 images now i want to display these images like this(in single row scroll able).

```
image1  image2 image3  image4  image5
```

But in mobile we can display 2 or 3 at a time. Can we set the number of rows in Grid View like `numColumn:2`?
Thanks for considering.

Comment: Do you want the images to scroll horizontally?

Comment: "Is there anyway to set the no of row" i don't think so.

Comment: then just set the number of columns to 5 and they will be shown in single row.

Comment: use Gallery even its deprecated, or ViewPager with imageViews

Comment: @MoshErsan i want to make the center image focus able when first time page will get loaded. How i can get this?

Comment: I think you could use something like android.widget.Gallery. The Gallery view itself is deprecated. You can find custom implementations that have similar functionality.

Comment: just set gallery.setSelectedPosition(index)

Comment: @GareginSargsyan i am using gallery working fine but only one image it displaying at a time. what should i do? i want to display minimum 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to display a fixed number of images (for example using `ImageView`) horizontally, the best solution is using `HorizontalScrollView` with a single horizontal `LinearLayout` child, which will contain the images. It will look something like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView ...
                   ... />
        <ImageView ...
                   ... />
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: i am using gallery working fine but only one image it displaying at a time. what should i do? i want to display minimum 2?

Comment: I would not suggest using Gallerty. It is deprecated. You can find custom open-source layouts with similar functionality. Another solution would be using a ViewFlipper which will contain LinearLayouts each containing two images,

Comment: in my case no of images is not confirm. Could u please provide me some good resources or sample code if u have already done it.Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'no of images is not confirm' ?

Comment: i meant i am getting form server can be 10 or 100. i want to display in horizontal scrollbale view in single row. and center image  will be selected by default.

Comment: like this
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583033/android-cover-flow-gallery-and-remove-space-between

Comment: You can try using this layout: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/10/android-coverflow/

Comment: But in last Comment is still saying that "sadly it extends from Gallery too, so it has all the weirdness around it."

Comment: Do we have better option from this. I am worrying about that. lot of comments over there "Library needs a serious update:
1.Uses a deprecated class.
2.Doesn’t scale in the correct way. should use relative sizes for : image size, gap, reflection , based on the size that the coverFlow view itself has, and not a precise size.
3.Has a serious bug: when the image size is set to something different from the default value, after scrolling , the centered image gets tilted."

Comment: i want to display n number of images in horizontal scroll view and minimum 3 images at a time. How can i do this??

Answer (score 1):

`GridView` is not really designed for this purpose, it is designed to display an indefinite amount of data in an efficient scrolling manner. If you want to create a static layout where you can discretely place items at specific locations, you should be looking at `GridLayout` or `TableLayout` instead.

from

[How to set a fixed number of rows in android gridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168734/how-to-set-a-fixed-number-of-rows-in-android-gridview)